# Mongoose: versioning of the whole document after each update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save every version of the whole document on every save to list all the versions on my frontend, what is the best solution to handle this ?

Comment: I think I can't do this because you can't duplicate the document with the same _id, i will delete my last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to keep the same _id (ObjectId) you can just duplicate the content and connect the old version to the new version by id.

```
const Example = new Schema({
    // your stuff
    oldVersion: {
        mongoose.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Example'
    }
});
```

Then you could intercept the update command and create a new document with the old version and update the with the new version.

```
Example.pre(['updateOne', 'findOneAndUpdate'], async function(next) {
    let doc = await Example.findOne(this.getFilter(), {
        _id: 0
    });
    await Example.create(doc)
    next();
});
```

Checkout this part of the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre for the interceptor and this for the reference https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref

Comment: After some improvements i used this solution thanks

Comment: I rather like to add a Filed named history of array type, when I update the document, I  copy it , push the old one into the history (remember to turn the old one to JSON by toJSON(), otherwise there will be a endless call-loop), then use the new one to replace the old one;